# PHP Tag Array into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert a string of given tags into a MySQL table, but it's not quite working out.

```
  $tags = array explode (", ", $_POST["tags"]);
  $tag_array = implode(", ", $tags);
```

My table has the columns tag_id(auto increment) and tag_name(where each item of array needs to go into)

How do I cycle through my array and make MySQL insert a blank value into tag_id (as it's auto incremented) and each of my array values into the tag_name column?

Comment: once you implode, you don't have an array anymore. you've got a STRING. and I hope you're using proper [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) defense mechanisms, and not just trying to stuff that string into your DB directly...

Comment: 1. I assume MySQL is using tag_id as a primary key, so dont insert a blank value, 2. `$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tags VALUES (?)")` combined with [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: I also suggest you program some logic to account for if a user enters data like: `apple, orange,banana, [three spaces]  tomato, [6 spaces]      etc.`.  You can do this easily by `trim($tags)` and/ or just separating by comma (without the space) like `explode(',', $_POST['tags']);`.

Comment: What is the purpose of your code in the example? `$tag_array` will be equal to `$_POST["tags"]` afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The code is all in very basic stages. It's used to bind tags to photos. I'm not sanitizing the string yet. This is still all on a local server trying to get it all working. I know I still have stuff like that to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention how you're accessing MySQL from within PHP, but using PDO you could do something like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

$insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table (tag_name) VALUES (:tag)');
$insert->bindParam(':tag', $tag, PDO::PARAM_STR);

foreach ($tags as $tag) $insert->execute();
```

Comment: I'm simply using     mysql_query in either a PHP while or foreach

Comment: @RudyvanSloten: [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) (along with the rest of the ancient `mysql` PHP extension) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Comment: Perfect. I will look into continuing with PDO. I've not been using PHP/MySQL for several years, so I'm rather out of touch with new developments. Your code works fine (:

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do a foreach loop and insert the tags?

```
foreach($tags as $tag_name)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES ($tag_name)");
}
```

Note that you should really be using PDO as mysql_query is outdated. This is just an example and you should do a little research on how to sanitize your data before inserting it. A simple Google search will get you going.

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently looking into PDO. I already know how to sanitize my data, but haven't written the code for this yet as I wanted to test basic functionality.